# Cannot get ui-router state params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Consider the following ui-router configuration:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.feed', {
    url: "/feed",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/feed.html",
        controller: "FeedCtrl"
      }
    }
  })
```

I have the following link in my app:

```
<a ui-sref="app.feed({ feedId: 5 })">My Link</a>
```

I'm trying to get the `feedId` in state params:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('FeedCtrl', function($state) {
  console.log($state.params);
});
```

But, unfortunately, `$state.params` is always `{}`.

What am I doing wrong?

**BONUS QUESTION**

I expect `FeedCtrl` to be initialised every time I click on the link, i.e. every time the state is changed to `app.feed`. So, If I change between `app.feed` state and some other state multiple times, I expect the `console.log` above to run multiple times. But, it looks like ui-router initialises `FeedCtrl` only once. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass a parameter - we have to define it:

```
 .state('app.feed', {
    url: "/feed/{feedId}",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/feed.html",
        controller: "FeedCtrl"
      }
    }
```

In this case we define it as **`{feedId}`**

See more here

- [URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters)

Some examples:

- `'/user/{id:[^/]*}'` - Same as `'/user/{id}'` from the previous example.
- `'/user/{id:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}}'` - Similar to the previous example, but only matches if the id parameter consists of 1 to 8 hex digits.
- `'/files/{path:.*}'` - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
- `'/files/*path'` - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.

In case we do have parameter defined, and we will navigate among states with different `feedId` values... we will really see, that that controller `FeedCtrl` is reinstantiated. That's how the `ui-router` was designed

Comment: My question is more about the `ui-sref="stateName({ param: value })"` syntax: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref
So, if I navigate using this syntax, how could I get the parameter?

Comment: To get that parameter, it must be defined: `url: "/feed/{param}"`. Then, we can let `$stateParams` to be injected into controller and the property with the same name will contain it. I.e. `app.feed({ feedId: 5 })` will be `$stateParams.feedId === 5`

Comment: Please check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24016943/1679310 and the plunker I created. You can see how the param is defined, passed and observed

Comment: I spent three days trying to figure this out and I needed to add the resolve.. Thanks!

Comment: How do use leverage `param` on the view? {{ param }} ?