# Angular ui-router nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to inject a nested view into my normal view, using ui-router.
I know it's possible by doing ng-include. But I want to solve it by using ui-router.

My html is as follow:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Project todos</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ui-view="todos"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in my script I got a state:

```
.state('project', {
   url: '/project/:projectId',
   templateUrl: 'views/project/project.html',
   controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
   views: {
      'todos': {
       templateUrl: 'views/project/todos.html'
      }
   }
})
```

**Update - isn't there something like this possible?**

```
.state('project', {
   url: '/project/:projectId',
   templateUrl: 'views/project/project.html',
   controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
   views: {
      'todos@project': {
         templateUrl: 'views/project/todos.html'
      }
   }
})
```

Anyone can find a typo or something? I've read the docs. I am not sure what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9wgfMkD6TE3eqhDpkM1?p=preview), showing how we can make it running

On the index.htm we need to have the `<div ui-view="" ></div>`, which is the place were we inject the project.html. Then we adjust the state definition, to inject also nested view - using `ui-view` absolute naming:

```
  .state('project', {
    url: '/project/:projectId',
    
    views: {
      '' : {
        templateUrl: 'views.project.project.html',
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
      },
      'todos@project': {
        templateUrl: 'views.project.todos.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

The absolute name `todos@project`, will inject the todos.html into the project.html. Check the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9wgfMkD6TE3eqhDpkM1?p=preview)

See the:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

A cite:

> ...Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of `viewname@statename`, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax...

Comment: In the index I just inject the view based on the URL. Isn't there another way? Because not every state has nested views. Only this one. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Not sure were is the issue!? Each **root** state *(there could be more of them)* must start somewhere. It must be injected into some top level view *(s)*. But that root state could define more views (not more states) as in my example. There is only **one** State `"project"`, which targets two views. One of them is in the index.html, the second is even part of the first one. With that you can achieve anything, just declare the `ui-view` where you want. I am not sure what I am missing...

Comment: So that means I have to make a "" view in every other state..?

Comment: Well sorry, I guess my code didn't updated in the browser. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Great to see that! because the `ui-router` is really awesome library!

Comment: Yes, it really is! Im getting used to it slowly!